# Finding local and global extrema of a function with a constraint

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

I'm working on a problem involving multivariable calculus and Lagrange multipliers and could use some help. The task involves finding local and global extrema of a function under a given constraint.

The functions are defined as follows:
$$f,g:R^3→R$$given by $$f(x)=∥x∥_2^4 +∥x∥_2$$
$$g(x)=x_1 − x_2^2$$
The goal is to find the local and global extrema of f under the constraint $$g(x)=0$$.

I know I need to set up the necessary first-order optimality conditions and find solutions of $$x^∗$$ and the corresponding Lagrange multipliers $$λ^∗$$, but I'm unsure how to proceed. Second-Order Optimality Conditions: Once I have the solutions, how do I compute the Hessian matrix of f to check the sufficient second-order optimality conditions for these solutions?

Any guidance or steps for solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For this problem, you will never have to compute the second order conditions.  Once you find all the points $u$ where $\nabla f(u) = \lambda g(u)$ and $g(u) =0$, you could just evaluate $f(u)$ for all those points to find the min and max.  (Note that $f$ is not differentiable everywhere, so you need to also find $f(u)$  for all points where $f(u)$ is not differentiable.)

Comment: This problem is both tricky and simple.  It's simple because you can visualize $g$ in your head and $f$ is radially symmetric.  Once you visualize $g$ you might realize that the min must occur at exactly one place on the surface $g=0$.

Comment: I computed the gradient of f and I got \nabla f(u) = 2x +$$x/∥x∥_2$$. How should I use the substitution u to find the solution?

Comment: I get $\nabla f(u) = 4 u \| u\|^2 + u /\| u \| = u (4 \|u\|^2 + 1/\|u\|)$.

Comment: Now, I get the following system of equations 

$$ x_1 (4∥x∥^2 +1/∥x∥) + λ        = 0$$
$$ x_2(4∥x∥^2 + 1/∥x∥) −2λx_2  = 0$$ 
$$ x_1(4∥x∥^2 1/∥x∥)                   = 0$$
$$    x_1 - (x_2)^2                        = 0 $$
I tried to solve the equations in order to find the solutions of x and λ but I didn't get any proper values.

Comment: Your equations should be    $$x_1 h(x) + \lambda=0,$$  $$x_2 h(x) + -2x_2\lambda=0,$$  $$ x_3 h(x) =0, $$ and $$ x_1 - (x_2)^2 = 0$$ where $h(x) = 4 \|x\|^2 + 1/ \|x\|$.  It's not too hard to show that these equations have no solutions!  So, any local min or max must occur where either $f$ or $g$ is not differentiable.  $g$ is differentiable everywhere.